# Webview content inside Tableviewcell autolayout iOS 8

Tags: uitableview, webview, ios8, autolayout

I am working on application in which I need to show web content inside tableview cell. Can you tell me how to accomplish this task? Any help will be appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is taking UIWebView inside the content View of table view cell.
[image: view hierarchy]

Comment: Can you give answer in detail please??

Comment: If you are working with storyboard u can drag and drop a UIWebView inside the tableview cell content view

Comment: No I have html string content in sqlite table that I want to display in tableviewcell.

Comment: can u provide sample of your code where you are loading the web view?